# How to activate frame manually in wxWidgets?

Tags: wxwidgets

I have wxWidget application. And somewhere on my MainFrame I create new frame and call Show on it. But, if an user will do this action again, I don't want to create new frame. I want to activate previous one. I store pointer to created frame, but I don't know how to send activation coomand to him? I tried to send ActivatedEvent in createdFrame->ProcessEvents, but no sense.

Is it possible to sent activate command to a frame wxWidgets?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the term "activate frame"  What does it mean?

Comment: A frame in wxWidgets is a simple window. Activate frame means to get focus to that window. And if window is in background - OS will bring it as current active window. I can do it via WinApi, but this way is Windows only and I want to use wxWidgets crossplatform approach, but I don't know is it supported by wxWidgets. BTW I using 2.8.12 wxWidgets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To grab the focus for a window, call the the method SetFocus()

```
wxFrame * pFrame = new wxFrame( ... );

...

pFrame->SetFocus();
```

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxwindow.html#wxwindowsetfocus

I wonder why you want to do this?  It is a bit strange!  Normally, people leave it up the the OS do this, when the user clicks on the window.  In fact, the wxFrame hardly ever gets the focus, because there is very little ( nothing? ) it can do with it.  What usually happens is that one of the widgets contained by the frame get the focus - for example a text control so the user can start typing into it.

Maybe this is what you really want to do?  In which case the procedure goes like this:

- Create a wxPanel that occupies the client area of the frame
- Add some widgets to the panel
- Call wxPanel::setFocus()   http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxpanel.html#wxpanelsetfocus

Comment: BTW. In my application there is a list with 3-5 items. And when an user click on list item - new frame with detail information is displayed. And by the logic of application there are can be displayed a couple of detail frames. And if a user will click again on list item and detail frame isn't closed - I want to call SetFocus() and frame will bring to front of application.